# Eclipse Shot-Cut not working (Open Call Hierarchy: Ctrl + ALT + H)

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have eclipse with the plug-ins from SAP. So it is called HANA Studio. (This eclipse is already bundled with the plug-ins so the icon is also different).

**The short-cut to open call hierarchy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>** (for Java development) **does not work.** Even though the shot-cut is defined properly.

I tried :

1. removing the short-cut
2. Reopening Eclipse
3. Add another short-cut.
4. Checked for conflicts.

Where 1 and 2 are not working. 3 is working but an undesired work-around. What else could be tried?

[image: Eclipse shot-cut settings]

What I also noticed is that the context-menu changes by adding another short-cut:

**Standard settings:**

[image: Eclipse standard]

**After adding a short-cut - I can not use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> again :/**

[image: After adding user short-cut]

Comment: Restarting eclipse fixed it for me (I was trying to bind 'Previous Word' to `Alt+H`)

Answer (score 2):

I've had exactly the same problem. My solution was to remove all filters (Button Filters...) and then I assigned the short cut to the uncategorized command. Also i unbinded the other command(s). I had to test some options for the "When:"-dropdown list. But now the short cut works again.

[image: working short-cut for Open Call Hierarchy]